# Знак "^" в Delphi. Что он означает?

Tags: delphi, символы

Что означает символ "^" в Delphi 7?

Answer (score 7):

Указатели в языке Pascal. Первые несколько ссылок от сервиса Сергея Брина:

- [Использование указателей](http://citforum.ru/programming/bp70_ug/bp70ug_08.shtml)
- [Указатели и динамическая память](http://klax.tula.ru/~zet/frames/thm_pointers.html)
- [Указатели](http://wm-help.net/books-online/book/79769/79769-23.html)
- [Указатели в Паскале. Динамическая память на языке Паскаль](http://life-prog.ru/view_algoritmleng.php?id=122)

Answer (score 7):

Ох, давненько я не брал в руки Паскалей :). Попробую в двух словах дополнить по синтаксису:

символ `^` (*"шляпка"*) в Паскале имеет два различных значения:

В блоке объявлений шляпка **перед** идентификатором типа объявляет **типизированный** указатель:

```
type P1 = ^T;
{ или }
var P2: ^T;
```

где `T` - идентификатор типа данных, `P1` - тип-указатель на тип `T`, `P2` - переменная-указатель на тип `T`.

В блоке реализации символ `^` **после** идентификатора переменной является оператором разыменования, т. е. обозначает, что в выражении участвует не значение самого указателя, а значение его родительского типа.

```
var X2: ^Real;  { X - указатель на действительное число }
begin
  X^ := Pi;  
  X^ := X^ / 2; { присвоит π/2 по указателю X }
end;
```

Comment: Не получилось в двух словах, прошу критиковать.

Answer (score 1):

Google что ли не работает.

Коротко вот

```
var X: ^Integer;// (X Указатель на Integer)
...
New(X);//(Выделить память по адресу X)
X^:=50;//(Записать туда число 50)
```

А подробнее - читайте про указатели и адреса.

Comment: Не обвиняйте человека зря — на символ «^» просто так не погуглишь ;)

Comment: [ВНЕЗАПНО!](http://google.com/search?q=circumflex+pascal)

Comment: Это еще знать надо что оно «карет» (а не циркумфлекс, кстати, последний — это диакритика, а не самостоятельный знак). Хотя, да, не поспоришь, при желании можно выгуглить. (Но когда я как-то искал что за комбинатор `<$>` такой в Haskell — было смешно)

Comment: Оно даже по запросу *шляпка в паскале* находится :-) А вообще, мне очень кажется, что мы сей вопрос уже обсуждали здесь на *stackoverflow.RU*